# Scala's syntax of of work with anonymous objects in map() & flatMap()

Tags: scala

As example, I have the following Scala class(and the same in C#, ofc):

```
import com.github.nscala_time.time.Imports._

class Flight{
  var FlDate:DateTime = new DateTime
  var Origin = ""
  var Destination = ""
}
```

flights = Flight[]

Original C# Code:

```
var rez = flights.SelectMany(p => new[] {
     new { Airport = p.Origin, IsOrigin = true },
     new { Airport = p.Destination, IsOrigin = false }
   })
   .GroupBy(x => x.Airport)
   .Select(g => new
   {
       Airport = g.Key,
       LeftCount = g.Count(x => x.IsOrigin),
       ArrivedCount = g.Count(x => !x.IsOrigin)
   });
```

Incorrect Scala code:

```
var rez = flights
  .flatMap(case (airport, isOrigin) => {
  new { airport = _.origin, isOrigin = true }, // issue - ?
  new { airport = _.destination, isOrigin = false } // issue - ?
})
.groupBy(_.airport)
.map {
  case (airport, leftCount, arrivedCount) => new {
    val airport = ??? // issue - g.Key?
    val leftCount = ??? // issue - g.Count(x => x.IsOrigin) ?
    val arrivedCount = ??? // issue - g.Count(x => !x.IsOrigin) ?
  }
}
```

So, as you see by the code, as result i need to have an array of objects with the following properties:  `ListBuffer[airport:String, leftCount :Int, arrivedCount:Int]`

So...

1. Can someone help to fix the code?
2. Maybe, someone knows some good article about "syntax of work with anonymous objects in Scala" topic?

Comment: You asked the same question a couple of days ago

Comment: Also please always at least mention the errors you got. Saying "issue" is not very informative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
val flights: Seq[Flight] = ...
// Let's represent the result in a Map[Airport, (Left, Arrived)]
val res: Map[String, (Int, Int)] = 
  flights
    .flatMap(flight => Seq((flight.origin, true), (flight.destination, false)))  // Seq[(String, Boolean)]
    .groupBy { case (airport, _) => airport }  // Map[String, List[(String, Boolean)]] 
    .mapValues { grouped =>
      val left = grouped.count { case (_, isOrigin) => isOrigin }
      val arrived = grouped.count { case (_, isOrigin) => !isOrigin }
      (left, arrived)
    }
```

Comment: 1. can you explain flatMap string logic? as I still do not understand how to write the same + 2. There is incorrectly grouping. I think it's because of this code return ListBuffer[(String, (Int, Int))] --  (I had fixed mistakes in your code) -- but must return ListBuffer[String, Int, Int]

Comment: expected and actual result you can find here: http://prntscr.com/esebss

Comment: Try again with the latest edit. I just tried this exact code and it works :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. But, can you explain flatMap string logic? Or to give some link with explanations how to write the same?

Comment: @Andrew `flatMap` and `SelectMany` are the same thing.